# 'grub-install /dev/sdb failed' while installing Ubuntu after Windows

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, windows-10

I am having two hard drives. My target is to install Ubuntu and Windows on the SSD but as I try to install Ubuntu on the partition which I created for it I am getting

```
grub-install /dev/sda failed
```

`sdb` is my SSD which has one partition for Windows and one for Ubuntu. `sdb5` is where I want to install Ubuntu, `sdb6` is the Reserved BIOS boot area and I selected `sda`, which is just a 1TB hard drive with data, as target for the bootloader.

I am not sure what the problem is here. Do I need another partition on `sda` for the bootloader? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a better coherence I suggest you to install grub loader on the device that contains your system partitions

Then you may have to create a dedicated EFI System Partition on the SSD in addition to Windows and Ubuntu ones.

some help: [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Installing_Ubuntu_in_UEFI_mode)

Comment: How can I do that? Since I've installed Windows 10 on the SSD isn't there already a bootloader installed that Windows is using?

Comment: Yes, there's always a bootloader one way or another. Irrelevant. What matters right now is *how* Windows was installed (UEFI or legacy) because you want to boot and install Ubuntu the same way.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Well, I think it's in UEFI mode. I got a 99MB partition that says "EFI System Partition". I always used to install Ubuntu on a second partition and a second bootloader on the other drive so I can switch between the two systems at startup by selecting one of the two drives.

Comment: With UEFI you don't need to. All installed OSes should have one or more entries in the ESP (EFI System Partition) and there should be one and only one. The Windows entry chainloads the Windows bootloader manager; the Ubuntu entry chainloads Grub. You don't need to tell the installer where to install Grub in UEFI mode, as a matter of fact you can't.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Okay, but what does that mean for the Ubuntu setup? The way I did it before led me to the `grub-install` error - what do I have to change then?

Comment: You need to boot the installer in UEFI mode because how it boots is how it installs. Before that boot Windows and disable fast startup and shutdown (reboot isn't enough for the settings to stick).